# Advice on creating "Query Builder"

Tags: php, sql, browser, builder

The system I manage has many entities from programs, projects, stages, departments, etc.
Many people in the company would like their own custom views of the different entities. Up until now, I have been creating the custom view myself, but it has come to a point where my boss has asked me to make a query maker so that each employee can create, save and view their own made queries whenever they please. They should be able to select the main data they want to view and then add conditions as well as choose how to display the data.

This is what I have so far in terms of database tables:

**queries**

```
id
name
desc
isglobal (1 or 0 value, whether the query can be seen by everyone else)
creator (id of user in system)
created (datetime)
entity (this would be the table name or a key which maps to the table name)
template (a template of tags that will be parsed to generate the HTML for that query page)
```

**query_conditions**

```
id
queries_id
field
value
```

So for example, let's say someone named Mark creates a query/view where it would show all "projects" that have him as a manager. There would be a row in both tables that look like this:

**queries:**

```
1
All projects managed by Mark
Shows all projects in the system currently managed by Mark
1
6
2012-04-23 00:00:00
project
```

**And this is what would be stored in the template field which is of type TEXT**

```
<!-- BEGIN: ROW -->
<tr>
<td>{PROJECT_NAME}</td>
<td>{PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}</td>
</tr>
<!-- END: ROW -->
```

**query_conditions:**

```
1
1 (this corresponds to the query id above)
manager
6 (this corresponds to Mark's user id in the system)
```

The database design I have is pretty straightforward and easy to manage for simple conditions. I'm already imagining more advanced conditions where you might want to see list of projects from any two managers, or three or whatever. I think the current design of the second table still works where I would just have an extra row with the same values for the first three columns, and a different value for the "value" column. I can do an SQL check at the beginning to see if I'm dealing with a 1-condional or an n-condition in which I would have to use OR in the SQL.

There are 2 problems I'm not sure how best to approach.

1. What type should the "value" field be. I'm thinking that 99% of the time, the value will be an integer, but obviously there will be a chance of a date or a string as well. What data type would you recommend? Probably not the best, but I was almost thinking BLOB where I could serialize and unserialize. Using BLOB, I could store arrays in that field which would save me from having to store multiple rows like I mentioned a few lines up.
2. The other thing is ranges. What if they wanted projects created between certain dates. Or, where the value of a column is between 5-10 for example. I wonder if this could be handled with an extra column called "max_value." If this column is not NULL, then we assume it's a range and "value" would be the min_value.
3. Any advice on the template Field. I will be making it a TEXT field which just gets parsed per row of the data returned for that custom query.

I thought it would be useful to show you the XML file that I am using. My boss doesn't want all fields of the table to be shown for creating these custom queries so we use the following XML data to filter which fields are "allowed."

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entities>
    <entity>
        <key>program</key>
        <table>program</table>
        <label>Programs</label>
        <allowed>1</allowed>
        <fields>
            <field>
                <key>name</key>
                <column>prg_name</column>
                <label>Name</label>
                <tag>{PROGRAM_NAME}</tag>
                <method>getName</method>
                <allowed>0</allowed>
            </field>
            <field>
                <key>description</key>
                <column>prg_desc</column>
                <label>Description</label>
                <tag>{PROGRAM_DESCRIPTION}</tag>
                <method>getDesc</method>
                <allowed>0</allowed>
            </field>            
        </fields>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <key>project</key>
        <table>product</table>
        <label>Projects</label>
        <allowed>1</allowed>
        <fields>
            <field>
                <key>name</key>
                <column>prd_name</column>
                <label>Name</label>
                <tag>{PROJECT_NAME}</tag>
                <method>getName</method>
                <allowed>0</allowed>
            </field>
            <field>
                <key>description</key>
                <column>prd_desc</column>
                <label>Description</label>
                <tag>{PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}</tag>
                <method>getDesc</method>
                <allowed>0</allowed>
            </field>
            <field>
                <key>manager</key>
                <column>prd_manager</column>
                <label>Manager</label>
                <tag>{PROJECT_MANAGER}</tag>
                <method>getManager</method>
                <allowed>1</allowed>
            </field>
            <field>
                <key>activity</key>
                <column>prd_activity</column>
                <label>Activity</label>
                <tag>{PROJECT_ACTIVITY}</tag>
                <method>getActivity</method>
                <allowed>1</allowed>
            </field>            
        </fields>
    </entity>   
</entities>
```

Comment: Actually, that's the main reason why SQL was invented - to allow non-technical people to query a database using plain english words. Having a web interface that only allows `SELECT` queries (with pretty formatted tables as output) and having some easy to follow guide on using them (from very simple to more complex) could be easier for people to use than a query browser.

Comment: I thought of that as well. However, my boss wants an interface which would allow employees to create these queries, and then save them for future use. There would basically end up being a page that lists the names of all the queries and it would allow people to quickly view each one 1 by 1.
The UI for the query builder is pretty much done where you go through a wizard of sorts. Step by step, you define your query, setup the conditions, choose what to display, and save. Basic conditions work pretty well at this point. Just not sure about the database setup. Especially how to handle ranges.

Answer (score 1):

If I were building it I would create the query like this:

"select"
then have a drop down for table.

then once table is populated use information_schema.columns to find all the columns in that table.

then have a listbox that you can add the columns to, thus building your column list.

finally add a second listbox to add where columns and allow the user to type associated data (aka add StartDate and a textbox they can type a date in).

Comment: I added some of my XML data that I am using for generating the query builder UI. Not all fields of a table are allowed to be filtered on according to my boss, so this is one of the reasons I use this XML file.

Answer (score 0):

We use [EasyQuery](http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-component/) components for such kind of tasks.
They have live demo which you can try for free: http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/asp-net-ajax/